# How to fill pad with polygon pour

Tags: altium, polygon

How can I fill the complete pad with polygon pour ? (I dont know the correct question in english)

I am using Altium Designer 17

[image]

Comment: Most likely you want to set the polygon pour to not have "thermal relief".  There are times this is justified, but beware it complicates soldering!

Comment: will be only for one pad

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways to do this either on an as-needed basis or globally. On every design I create a rule as seen in the photo.  Then, for example, if you want just a select number of pads (on a net that I may not want ALL pads flooded for that net) flooded with copper I will create a small polygon (to place on top of the parent polygon) just big enough to cover the pad in question and name this polygon "Pin Flood".[image]

Or, if you want ALL pads flooded for ALL nets then just change the default "PolygonConnect" to Connect Style==>Direct Connect.

And for lesson #2. You can also create a Pad Class as you see in this photo.
[image]

Then create a new rule in Polygon Connect that you see in this photo.
[image]
This method is a bit more portable and easier to manage.

EDIT ...and as Chris Stratton points outs above. Flooded copper on TH pads *may* complicate soldering in terms of proper wetting of the solder fillet. One can always change the rule set from "Direct Connect" to "Relief Connect" and fatten-up the thermal ties.

Comment: Ooooh great!! Thanks I need only for terminal screw power supply